# Math error computing log(det(AA^T)+1) in python

Tags: python, math, determinants

I am trying to estimate the mean value of log(det(AA<sup>T</sup>)+1) in Python. My simple code works fine until I get to 17×17 matrices at which point it gives me a math error.  Here is the code:

```
iter = 10000
for n in xrange(1,20):
    h = n
    dets = []
    for _ in xrange(iter):
        A = (np.random.randint(2, size=(h,n)))*2-1
        detA_Atranspose = np.linalg.det(np.dot(A, A.transpose()))
        try:
            logdetA_Atranspose = math.log(detA_Atranspose+1,2)
        except ValueError:
            print "Ooops!", n,detA_Atranspose
        dets.append(logdetA_Atranspose)
    print np.mean(dets)
```

A is supposed to be a matrix with elements that are either -1 or 1.

What am I doing wrong and how can it be fixed?  What is special about 17?

Comment: There's nothing special about 17. it's just that you can't compute the log of detA_Atranspose <= 0.

Comment: @JohnTitusJungao Why doesn't those matrices exist for n < 17?

Comment: I got the error for n = 16. [Here's a screenshot](http://imgur.com/MqGwrvd)

Comment: @JohnTitusJungao ah :)

Comment: You should correct your title to the actually used formula `log(1+det(AA^T), 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For the formula in the title ( previously logdet(AA^T) ):

det(AA^T) for some random As can simply be 0. 
The function would then fail because computing log(0) is invalid.

Note that in theory det(AA^T) cannot be negative, since AA^T is a [positive semi-definite matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) (which means that all eigenvalues are non-negative and implies that det >= 0).

### For the formula in the code ( logdet(1+AA^T) )

You should probably use `numpy.linalg.slogdet()` and compute `slogdet(1+A.dot(A.T))`

From its [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.slogdet.html):

"Compute the sign and (natural) logarithm of the determinant of an array.

**If an array has a very small or very large determinant, then a call to det may overflow or underflow.** This routine is more robust against such issues, because it computes the logarithm of the determinant rather than the determinant itself."

Comment: You're right about the +1 in log(1+AA^T). I guess I took it from the title...  so, it can only happen due to overflow.

Comment: The proposed use of `slogdet` should convert the computation to floating point, which also will repair the integer overflow problem. However, with a rather small probability, the determinant can still be zero.

Comment: "det(AA^T) cannot be negative"... it does appear to be though according to the code.

Comment: @eleanora only due to overflow, presumably.

Comment: slogdet(1+A.dot(A.T))  doesn't give 0 when A is singular sadly so I get a lot of `-inf` values.

Comment: @Cimbali: No, only many medium sized eigenvalues that amplify floating point noise at zero eigenvalues. Like degenerate noisy eigenvalue times remaining product of eigenvalues equals `-1e-15*16^14=-2^-50*2^56=-2^6`, as can happen in the case `n=16`.

Comment: @eleanora:Just cut off the negative determinants at zero as obvious results of a noisy singular matrix.

Comment: This could be another solution to your original problem: compute logdet(1 + AA^T + pI), where p is a small scalar (say 1e-6), and I is the identity matrix. This should get rid of instability issues at the expense of accuracy.

Comment: @LutzL are you sure? Because on a 64 bit signed integer overflow would occur at 2^63, and `ln(2^63) = 43.6`, not impossibly far off values already observed... I don't know for a fact whether the internals of `numpy.linalg.det` are done in floating point or integer math, but the documentation does say it is subject to overflows.

Comment: Though I guess it doesn't make much sense to use integer math if you may expect floating point values in your input matrices.

Comment: @Cimbali: Yes, that is very suggestive, but the problem stays the same if you force floating point values via `A = (np.random.randint(2, size=(h,n)))*2-1.0`. Also, the wrongly negative values are not negative integers, but have non-trivial fractional parts.